# Cant Access Magento Frontend After Migrating to new Server

Tags: error, magento1.9.2.3

I have migrated my magento store to live server, after migration when i access my magento store it says

```
The domain.example.com page isn’t working

domain.example.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500
```

But when i access Admin Panel of magento store it works as before without any interruptions.

when i take a look at my system log it says:

```
2016-09-06T09:47:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:47:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:47:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Parent.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/local:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/community:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/core:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:47:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:47:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:47:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Parent.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/local:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/community:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/core:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Parent.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/local:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/community:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/core:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Parent.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/local:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/community:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/core:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Parent.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/local:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/community:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/core:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Parent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-06T09:48:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Parent.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/local:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/community:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/core:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')  in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

What does this error means? This magento store running on php version 5.4 and i have uploaded and re uploaded setup files 2 or 3 times even the database too. any help is appreciated.

Comment: from where Parent.php included ?

Comment: in root of magento, you can see `index.php` file, take the backup of that file & uncomment these lines in that file : `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);` , Than check frontend....

Comment: thanks for your quick response, @minesh any idea where this file could be..??

Comment: @BabyinMagento after uncommenting these lines i got some warnings in front-end..  these warnings says :

Comment: 'Warning: include(.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Warning: include(.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Comment: no @Lalit838 i am not sure about Parent.php file in default magento setup

Comment: Warning: include(): Failed opening '.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/local:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/community:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/app/code/core:/home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/chilliscoop/public_html/originatedemo/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Comment: that same error for Parent.php file

Comment: try to find "Parent.php"  word in your local magento setup

Comment: @Lalit838 are you using any extensions or do you have ssh access ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento no i m not using much extensions just a attribute manager and a sw-megamenu thats all. and sorry i dont have ssh access.

Comment: @MineshPatel there are more then 15 parent.php files in magento setup, which one to go for. all files are different.

Comment: yes @Lalit838 it's complicate to determine this issue

Comment: try to var_dump($class) in file lib/Varien/Autoload.php in function autoload

Comment: Thanks @MineshPatel var_dump($class) helped me out, the problem is resolved and was causing by a custom module i created. thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Lalit838 great... !! :)

Comment: @MineshPatel don't you want to post an answer ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento let me do that

Answer (score 1):

try to var_dump($class) in

> file lib/Varien/Autoload.php

in function `autoload()`

It will print class name so that you will get idea about missing include file